# Finding sum when values are in dtype object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to pandas and dataframes. I'm trying to find the total income ('tot_income') for all products ('product') from a given manufacturer ('manufacturer' = 'Audi'). So in other words, I want to find the sum of 'total_income' for 'Audi'.

One problem is that in each cell in the 'total_income' column, the value is given with the dollar sign ($100000), so the .sum method doesn't work, as the data type is object.

This was my best try, which gave me the error message:
"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

```
TotalManIncome = df.loc[df['manufacturer'] == 'Audi', 'total_income'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df_data = {'manufacturer': ['audi', 'maly_rysiu_bez_zebow', 'maly_rysiu_bez_zebow'],'price': ['$1000', '$2000', '$400000']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data)
df['price'] = df['price'].str.slice(1).astype(float)
df.loc[df['manufacturer'] == 'maly_rysiu_bez_zebow']['price'].sum()
```

Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html to erase $ sign.

Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html to change it from string to float so the sum operation is performed on numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should first clean the data. Use something like

```
df.total_income = df.total_income.map(lambda price:int(price[1:]))
```

to edit the row into integers. This expects to have an integer number after the first symbol in each of your prices.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `$` and convert to numeric:

```
df['total_income'] = df['total_income'].str.replace('\$', '').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Step :** You need to change all the value in total_income to int or float:

**INT:**

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['total_income'][i] = int(df['total_income'][i][1:])
```

**FLOAT:**

```
for i in range(len(df)):
        df['total_income'][i] = float(df['total_income'][i][1:])
```

**Second Step :** after that you can use `.sum()`